# DisplayMember ComboBox For Which Contains List<Object> as item source

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have Comobox likes this

```
 <dxe:ComboBoxEdit AutoComplete="True" IsTextEditable="False" ImmediatePopup="True" IncrementalFiltering="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Example}" />
```

In Vm

```
 public List<object> Example
            {
                get { return example; }
                set { example = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Example")); }
            }
   public List<ArticlesStock> ArticlesStockList
        {
            get { return articlesStockList; }
            set
            {
                articlesStockList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ArticlesStockList"));
            }
        }

  Example.Add(ArticlesStockList);
```

In `ArticlesStock` class, I have Prop Name `Producer` a string

How can I set this as my path in ComboBox?
normally we can just set this with props. but here I have a list .and inside I have one more list. in this list the first item value must be set.
C# Conversion how can I set this as Display member

```
((List<ArticlesStock>)Example[0])[0].WarehouseDeliveryNoteItem.Producer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following: define a `DataTemplate` for your combobox's items and use a converter to retrieve the property you need.

DataTemplate definition:

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Example}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type List}">
            <!--no Path is specified, which is equivalent to Path="."-->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConv}}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And the converter used to access the Producer property:

```cs
public class MyConv : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // here value will be an item of Example list, so a List<ArticlesStock>
        var val = value as List<ArticlesStock>;
        return val[0].Producer;
    }
}
```

Note that I simplified your model structure for brevity.

Comment: Actually, I left this approach and created proper records and using it I think this will work but I can't use it. I will get a  circular dependency and  `[0].WarehouseDeliveryNoteItem.Producer` u can use like this in display member if anyone  is wondering plus one for effort

Comment: i think it will create a problem when displaying the selected item in ComboBox we need to maintain a template there too.

Comment: You could use a converter there too, but I think a better structured model (as you already did in your first comment) is the best way to go.